# difference between np.linalg.lstsq and linear regression in scikit learn

Tags: pandas, scikit-learn

**comb 1** is a  **pandas data frame** with following values.

yearID    teamID      salary          W
408             ANA          51464167      82 
409            ARI         81027833        85

When I use *np.linalg.lstsq* I am able to print dfg data frame.

```
dfg = pd.DataFrame()

comb1 = combined[combined['yearID'] == 2000]
x1 = comb1['salary'].values /1000000 
y1 =comb1['W'].values
A1 = np.array([x1, np.ones(len(x1))])
w1 = np.linalg.lstsq(A1.T,y1)[0]
yq = (w1[0]*x1+w1[1])
dfg['New val'] = y1 - yq
```

When I use scikit learn libary for the linear regression and do the same operation I am getting a value error

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
fg = pd.DataFrame()

x2 = comb1['salary'].values /1000000 
y2 =comb1['W'].values

x2_reshape = x2.reshape(-1,1)
y2_reshape = y2.reshape(-1,1)

clf1 = LinearRegression()
clf1.fit(x2_reshape, y2_reshape)
predicted_train = clf1.predict(x2_reshape)

 x_pre = y2 - predicted_train 
fg['New val'] = x_pre
```

What is the difference between these two ?? kindly help me!!

Comment: Please post the results of your code and the error.

Answer (score 0):

They should be the [same](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.html):

```
Notes

From the implementation point of view, this is just plain Ordinary Least Squares (scipy.linalg.lstsq) wrapped as a predictor object.
```

If you getting an error, it's probably because of they way you set up your data.